# vb.net oledb Insert data into table

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, dbconnection

i want add data to the table in vb.net.
use Access, oledb and oledbcmmand.
Properties of all of the columns in the table is a short text.
i try this code but i can't insert the data.
i seem to understand me wrong oledb.
Please point out the wrong part.

```
    Dim HCSDB As New OleDbConnection
    HCSDB = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\HCS\HCSDB.mdb")
    'Dim sQuery As String
    Dim oleCmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim OleTran As OleDbTransaction

    Try
        HCSDB.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Open err", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Try
        oleCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO InfoManage ( SchoolName, BeforeCheck, SendName, SendNum, RecvName, RecvNum, SendTime, SendMsg, UserPass) VALUES (@SchoolName, @BeforeCheck, @SendName, @RecvName, @RecvNum, @SendTime, @SMSCheck, @SendMsg, @UserPass)"
        oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolName", edtSchoolName.Text)
        oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BeforeCheck", cBefore)
        oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SendName", edtSendName.Text)
        oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SendNum", edtSendTel.Text)
        oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecvName", edtRecvName.Text)
        oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecvNum", edtRecvTel.Text)
        oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SendTime", sTime)
        oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SendMsg", edtMsg.Text)
        oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPass", edtPass.Text)

        OleTran = HCSDB.BeginTransaction
        oleCmd.Transaction = OleTran
        oleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        OleTran.Commit()

        MsgBox("saved", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        'MsgBox(sQuery)
    Catch ex As OleDbException

        MsgBox("err", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

    End Try
    HCSDB.Close()

End If
```

Comment: what is the error you get? (remove try catch block or show the ex.ToString() as MsgBox text and check the error you get)

Comment: http://imgur.com/bKdf8Vq it is remove try catch block error

Answer (score 0):

You're not associating the command with the connection anywhere.  If you had actually looked at the error message provided by the exception then you would have seen that.  You need to either set the `Connection` property of the command object or else pass both the SQL statement and the connection to the constructor.

Also, what's the point of using a transaction for a single insert?  If it's for learning purposes then that's one thing but you then need to learn to roll-back on failure.  There's nothing to roll back in this case though, demonstrating the uselessness of the transaction.  The point of a transaction is to roll back previous successful steps if a later step fails.  There's only one step in your code, so no point to a transaction.

Comment: I do not know why it is needed . ,However , I have copied the code of my boss .

Comment: You should learn what transactions are for then, so you know if and when they are needed.  In brief, the idea is to be able to perform multiple operations as a unit, so that they all succeed or none do. If you're only performing one operation then there's no point to a transaction.